# Laravel multi condition query

Tags: php, laravel

I want to search for users previous relations but not sure how to make this logic happen.

## Logic

1. My table has 2 columns `from_id` `to_id` (both will get users ids)
2. I am sending 2 ids to back-end (one as input, another one in request header)
3. I want to say: `where`input id is from_id and header id is to_id`OR`where input id is to_id and header id is from_id` return the result otherwise is null obviously.

Note:
The part that I'm stuck in is `and` in conditions `input id is from_id` **and** `header id is to_id` OR `where input id is to_id` **and** `header id is from_id`

## Code

currently I have half way code which is this:

```
public function check(Request $request) {
  // user id from header request (request sender) e.g `1`
  $user = $request->user();
  // second user id (not sure where to use it yet) e.g `4`
  $request->input('receiverId');

  $chat = PrivateChat::where('from_id', $user->id)->orWhere('to_id', $user->id)->first();
}
```

**To make it simple**

> Basically I want return old chat between the 2 ids regardless of who was sender (from_id) and who was receiver (to_id).

Any idea how to make my logic happen?

## Update

this is my full code and it always return false while i do have previous chat between users with id `1` and `4`.

```
public function check(Request $request) {
    $user = $request->user();

    $chat = PrivateChat::where([['from_id', $user->id],['to_id',$request->input('receiverId')]])
    ->orWhere([['from_id', $request->input('receiverId')],['to_id',$user->id]])->first();

    $receiver = User::where('id', $request->input('receiverId'))->first();

    if($chat) {
        return response()->json([
            'data' => new PrivateChatResource($chat),
            'exist' => true,
            'receiver' => new UserResource($receiver),
            'message' => 'Chat data retrieved successfully.'
        ]);
    } else {
        return response()->json([
            'exist' => false,
            'receiver' => new UserResource($receiver),
            'message' => 'Chat data retrieved successfully.'
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: **NOTE:** Due to the bug in answer of this question I've managed to fixed it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62500246/laravel-conditional-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i see it you want to do the boolean logic, if wrong please correct me.

```
(from_id = header_id AND to_id = header_id) OR (from_id = input_id AND to_id = input_id)
```

This can be obtained with the following `Eloquent` query. Using `where($cloure)` syntax, for doing the boolean logic listed above. Calling where with a closure, adds parenthesis to your logic, everything within the clojure will be wrapped in ().

```
$user = $request->user();

$userInput = $request->input('receiverId');

PrivateChat::where(function ($query) use ($user) {
    $query->where('from_id', $user->id)->orWhere('to_id', $user->id);
})->orWhere(function ($query) use ($userInput) {
    $query->where('from_id', $userInput)->orWhere('to_id', $userInput);
})->first();
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi @mrhn , I have problem with this code in all times it returns true, even when there is actually no record with provided data. `Code` https://gist.github.com/robertnicjoo/61554cd9f5853642e6eb62d79a49887d

Comment: I would assume the authenticated users has rows in the db?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly your `where` logic looks like this:

```
('from_id' = $user->id  &  'to_id' = $request->input('receiverId'))
|| ('from_id' = $request->input('receiverId')  &  'to_id' = $user->id)
```

You can define multiple conditions in a single `where`:

```
PrivateChat::where([['from_id', $user->id],['to_id',$request->input('receiverId')]])
->orWhere([['from_id', $request->input('receiverId')],['to_id',$user->id]])->first();
```

`->first()` will return the first record that meets one of the conditions, but if you want  all results you can use `->get()`.

Comment: yes you understood it right. I shared an update please check it.