# Laravel conditional query

Tags: php, laravel

I have function where I try to search in 2 columns for matched id but in all times it return `true` even where there is actually no result.

I want to search for users previous relations but not sure how to make this logic happen.

## Logic

1. My table has 2 columns `from_id` and `to_id` (both will get users ids)
2. I am sending 2 ids to back-end (one as input, another one in request
   header)
3. I want to say: **where** input `id` is `from_id` and header id is
   `to_id` , **ORwhere** input `id` is `to_id` and header `id` is `from_id` return the result otherwise is null obviously.

## Code

```
public function check(Request $request) { // always return true!
        $user = $request->user();
        $userInput = $request->input('receiverId');
        $chat = PrivateChat::where(function ($query) use ($user) {
            $query->where('from_id', $user->id)->orWhere('to_id', $user->id);
        })->orWhere(function ($query) use ($userInput) {
            $query->where('from_id', $userInput)->orWhere('to_id', $userInput);
        })->first();

        $receiver = User::where('id', $request->input('receiverId'))->first();

        if($chat) {
            return response()->json([
                'data' => new PrivateChatResource($chat),
                'exist' => true,
                'receiver' => new UserResource($receiver),
                'message' => 'Chat data retrieved successfully.'
            ]);
        } else {
            return response()->json([
                'exist' => false,
                'receiver' => new UserResource($receiver),
                'message' => 'Chat data retrieved successfully.'
            ]);
        }
}
```

> **Note:**  this is follow up of my [older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62123538/laravel-multi-condition-query).

**Any idea what is the issue?**

## Update

Based on `Giacomo M` comment i think this should be the final code

```
$chat = PrivateChat::where(function ($query) use ($user, $userInput) {
            $query
                ->where('from_id', $user->id)
                ->where('to_id', $userInput);
        })->orWhere(function ($query) use ($user, $userInput) {
            $query
                ->where('from_id', $userInput)
                ->where('to_id', $user->id);
        })->first();
```

**makes sense?**

Answer (score 0):

You use `orWhere` also in the subqueries, but according to your logic you need AND in the subqueries.

Your query becomes:

```
$chat = PrivateChat::where(function ($query) use ($user) {
    $query
        ->where('from_id', $user->id)
        ->where('to_id', $user->id); // where, NOT orWhere
})->orWhere(function ($query) use ($userInput) {
    $query
        ->where('from_id', $userInput)
        ->where('to_id', $userInput); // where, NOT orWhere
})->first();
```

Comment: very good, i think they also need to use `$userInput` and `$user->id` in each set, not only for 1 of the sets each

Comment: I think the problem is you use same id for both columns `>where('from_id', $userInput) | ->where('to_id', $userInput)` and `->where('from_id', $user->id) | ->where('to_id', $user->id)`

Comment: shouldn't be like `->where('from_id', $user->id) | ->where('to_id', $userInput)`?